# ActionEvent textfield checking

Tags: java, forms, java-me, lwuit

I have cashform with atttributes pin,sendername,receivername,senderphone,amount and another form accountfrom with attributes pin,sendername receivername,senderphone,amount,bankname,account number..

both form have send Command 
 Now, I want to check whether the textfields are empty when the user clicks send button...

I tried it in this way

```
 if ( ae.getCommand() == send && ae.getSource()==cashpayform){
           cashcheck();
 }
if ( ae.getCommand() == send && ae.getSource()==accpayform){
           acccheck();
}
```

but its not working can anyone help me
thanx

Comment: Check if the spelling is same and wrap the "send" and "cashpayform" etc in quotes. And what are Cashcheck() and acccheck().

Comment: ya the spell is same .. cashcheck and acccheck are method to check empty fields

Comment: Try wrapping 'send' 'cashpayform' in quotes

Comment: Either ae.getCommand() does not equal send, or ae.getSource() does not equal cashpayform or accpayform. The problem is not in this code, it's some other place in your application. The best way to find out is to run with a debugger and set a breakpoint on the conditionals, and see why they're not triggering.

Answer (score 1):

When a command triggers an event the source of the event is the Command not the button so you can't physically make a distinction between a command triggered from a button press and a command triggered from a menu.

I suggest you use two different commands if you need to make a distinction between the source of the commands, they can have the same name and even ID if you make pointer comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare strings using `==`, instead use..

```
send.equals(ae.getCommand())
```